# Query with ORDER BY clause and sending certain rows at the end of the results separately

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

Given that I want to query over a single table and this table has this **structure** and **data**

```
price | weight
 100      0
 200     10
 500      0
 300     10
```

I would like to apply an *ORDER BY price DESC* but **I want also results with *weight = 10* to be at the end of the results** (and these results also applying the ORDER BY price DESC).

```
Results Query A         WHERE weight <> 10
----------------
price | weight
100       0
500       0

Results Query B         WHERE weight = 10
----------------
price | weight
200       10
300       10
```

I have thought in using *UNION* but I can't achieve this  which is what I want:

```
EXPECTED RESULT      <= order by price DESC
----------------
price | weight
500       0
100       0
300      10      <=
200      10      <= but maintaining rows with weight 10 at the end of the results
```

How would you do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort first by the boolean expression `weight = 10`, all such rows will be placed at the bottom of the resultset:

```
ORDER BY weight = 10,
         price DESC
```

because `weight = 10` is evaluated as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.